# Getting the value of $n$

Tags: arithmetic

It's strange. I can't get the value of $n$. Could someone give me the step by step way of getting the value of $n$. The answer key says $20$.

$$
1+\frac{i}{n}=\frac{1+\frac{i}{4}}{1+\frac{i}{5}}
$$

Comment: for what stands $i$ here? is $i^2=-1$?

Comment: it's not the imaginary i, Sir.

Comment: it's of some rate of interest.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

So, you have $$1+\frac{i}{n}=\frac{1+\frac{i}{4}}{1+\frac{i}{5}}$$ Simplify the rhs  so $$1+\frac{i}{n}=\frac{5 (i+4)}{4 (i+5)}$$ Substract $1$ from each side; reduce to same denominator to get $\frac{i}{n}$; take the inverse to get $\frac{n}{i}$; multiply both sides by $i$ to get $n$ as a function of $i$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 2):

I have got

$$1+\frac{i}{n}=\frac{20+5i}{20+4i},$$

$$\frac{i}{n}=\frac{i}{2+4i},$$

and thus $n=4(5+i)$.

Comment: The second line should be $\frac{i}{n}=\frac{i}{20+4i}$